# preg replace only numbers between parenthesis

Tags: preg-replace

I need to replace numbers between parenthesis. For example

```
(1) should be (<a href="1">1</a>) --> I could do this
(1,2,5,8) should be (<a href="1">1</a>,<a href="2">2</a>,<a href="5">5</a>,<a href="8">8</a>)
(2-5, 13) should be (<a href="2">2</a>-<a href="5">5</a>,<a href="13">13</a>)
```

I could not do the last two conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
//Config
$pattern='/\((\d|\s|,|\d+-\d+)+\)/';
$replacement='<a href="$0">$0</a>';
$subject='foo 1 bar (baz) (1) whatever (2,3,4) something (7-9,11) more';


//Callback
$callbackbody="return preg_replace('/\d+/','$replacement',\$matches[0]);";
$callback=create_function('$matches',$callbackbody);


//main
echo preg_replace_callback($pattern, $callback, $subject);
?>
```

Comment: thank you very much. but this code also removes "(" and ")". I want to keep paranthesis.

Comment: Changed my answer because I missed that: It makes the code easier, just dropped the line from the anonymous function, that activly removed the paranthesis

Comment: updated again to get rid of the ugly `global` and tidy up callback.

Comment: thans a lot, it is OK nad so practical.